# Demonstrate that 4k + 3 cannot be perfect square

Tags: square-numbers

I wonder if it can be mathematically demonstrated that

```
4k + 3 != n^2 where k,n are N (natural) numbers?
```

My daughter (6's grade) has a problem and the book's answer is just enumerating k elements

{3,7,11,19,23,27...}

saying that they cannot be perfect square.

Thank you,

Comment: sorry, typo, it's square!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the square of an even number is $(2m)^2 = 4m^2 = 4k$.

The square of an odd number is $(2m+1)^2 = 4m^2 +4m+1 = 4k + 1$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Odd+even(here, $2$) is also odd.

Comment: @jiten I don't understand your comment.

Comment: $4k+1$ is odd, $+2$ is odd too. Sorry, was wrong. You meant $(2m+1)^2+(\sqrt{2})^2 $ $\ne (2m+1)^2+2.(2m+1)\sqrt{2} + 2$.